# SQL Server Log shipping standby db stuck restoring

Tags: sql-server-2005, log-shipping

I have 2 servers on SQL Server 2005 SP4. When the secondary server catches up with the log files it is switches into standby mode, but after a while it seems to be 'stuck' in restoring.

There were some open connections & queries on the database, but these have now been closed. The copy and restore jobs are running fine, but its not being switched into standby. Can't see any transactions in the dmvs.

Can I attempt to manually restore the database with STANDBY option to switch it into standby? or will this break the log shipping (need to be careful as snapshot 300GB from a live website)

or is there anything else I need to check for task, etc blocking the switch to Standby..

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the log shipping configuration has reverted to NORECOVERY instead of STANDBY.

I think the is that there must have been an open session on the database, SSMS or alike and after a set period the log shipping is configured to revert back to NORECOVERY. The original configuration was did not have the 'disconnect users currently connected' option enabled.

To resolve the issue I simply went back into the original database and selected ship transaction logs and then selected the radio button for STANDBY instead of NORECOVERY